# pd.groupby in two columns sum() function does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to do the next example. I want to get the total number of survivors (*survived*) and the total amount paid per class (*fared*) using the Titanic dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bvalgard/data/main/titanic.csv')

df.groupby(['pclass'])[['survived', 'fare']].sum()
```

When I run this code, I only get the total number of survivors, but not the total amount paid. However, if I use other functions such as `.min()`, `.max()` etc it works.

What is the problem with the `.sum()` function then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you don't have numerical values but objects (`df['fare'].dtype` gives `dtype('O')`, `df['survived'].dtype` gives `dtype('int64')`), and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) silently drops invalid columns. You must convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
(df.assign(fare=pd.to_numeric(df['fare'], errors='coerce'))
   .groupby(['pclass'])[['survived', 'fare']].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
        survived        fare
pclass                      
1            200  28265.4043
2            119   5866.6374
3            181   9418.4452
```

##### Why does it fail?

[`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) only works with numeric data by default (`numeric_only=True`), while [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) has a default of `False` as it's more flexible to handle a wider range of data types (you can for instance compare strings, `max(['A', 'B'])` give `'B'`).

##### Can't I use `numeric_only=False`?

Yes, you can, but this would concatenate the strings rather than adding numerical values, which is not what you want:

```
df.groupby(['pclass'])[['survived', 'fare']].sum(numeric_only=False)

        survived                                               fare
pclass                                                             
1            200  211.3375151.55151.55151.55151.5526.5577.958305...
2            119  24241311.510.526261311.510.51310.512.525262626...
3            181  7.5520.2520.2520.257.657.657.9257.22927.258.05...
```